# Liferay Set Page Layout permission programmatically

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

My requirement is such that I have to programmatically create organization pages and set permission to them. So far I created organization public pages

```
layout = LayoutLocalServiceUtil.addLayout(_defaultUserId, _groupId, PRIVATE_LAYOUT, PARENT_LAYOUT_ID, pageSetting.name, pageSetting.title, description, TYPE, pageSetting.hidden, pageSetting.url, serviceContext);
LayoutLocalServiceUtil.updateLayout(layout.getGroupId(), layout.isPrivateLayout(), layout.getLayoutId(), layout.getTypeSettings());
```

But the public pages has `guest` view permission. I want to remove that `view` permission from guest user programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to find role "Guest" for current Liferay instance (company):

```
long userRoleId = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(_companyId, "Guest").getRoleId();
```

Afterwards you need to remove a permission:

```
ResourcePermissionLocalServiceUtil.removeResourcePermissions(
    _companyId,
    layout.getModelClassName(),
    ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL,
    String.valueOf(layout.getPrimaryKey()),
    userRoleId,
    new String[]{ActionKeys.VIEW}
);
```

**EDIT**: updated according comment

Comment: With several combination finally it worked. The role with `Guest` and scope with `INDIVIDUAL` worked finally. yay !!